# How can I check collisions of 2 sprites groups?

Tags: python, pygame

How do I check the collisions between the `bullet_grou` and the `enemy_group` and if they collide I want them do disappear. I have looked at few simular questions but none of them helped me. Thenks for all the help.
This game is supposed to be a simular game to the asteroids. #I dont know what more to specify here bt it doesnt let me post this question if I dont write some more over her sorry

```py
import pygame ,  sys
from random import randint
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill((255,255,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width/2,screen_height/2))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    def create_bullet(self):
        return Bullet(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0],pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1])

    def create_enemy(self):
        return Enemy(randint(50,screen_width-50),-200)
    
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((5,25))
        self.image.fill((255,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (pos_x,pos_y))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 5
        if self.rect.y <= -200:
             self.kill()
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill((255,140,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (pos_x,pos_y))
##    def __init__(self):
##        super().__init__()
##        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
##        self.image.fill((255,128,128))
##        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (randint(0,screen_width),-200))
##
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 5
        
        if self.rect.y >= screen_height + 200:
             self.kill()
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width, screen_height = 800, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

obstacle_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(obstacle_timer,150)
player = Player()
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(player)
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           # enemy_group.add(player.create_enemy())  
            bullet_group.add(player.create_bullet())
        if event.type == obstacle_timer:
            if randint(0,2):
                enemy_group.add(player.create_enemy())
##        if Enemy.rect.coliderect(Bullet.rect):
##            print('colision')                
    screen.fill((30,30,30))
    bullet_group.draw(screen)
    bullet_group.update()    
#    collide_enemy_bullet = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet_group, Enemy , False) #HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    collide_player_enemy = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_group, False)    
    for s in collide_player_enemy:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), s.rect, 5, 1)
        print('collide_player_enemy')
##    for x in collide_enemy_bullet:
##        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), x.rect, 5, 1)#HERE ALSO
##        print('collide_enemy_bullet')
        
    player_group.draw(screen)
    player_group.update()
    enemy_group.draw(screen)
    enemy_group.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(240)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pygame.sprite.groupcollide() should do the trick. You pass in the first group and the second group, and whether you want each group to disappear on collision.

```py
# True means you want them to disappear on collision
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullet_group, enemy_group, True, True)
```

Pygame docs: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide

Comment: Thx a lot i wasnt able to figure out how to do it for a long time